# Php use of bindParam in SQLite

Tags: php

When I try to add something to the sqlite databse the result is always false. Where is the error? I don't get an exception so I think the code is correct by syntax. Please help me

```
public function add(ChatMessage $chatMessage){        
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO chatmessage(id,authorName,message) VALUES(:id,:authorName,:message)');

        $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':authorName',$authorName);
        $stmt->bindParam(':message',$message);

        $id = $chatMessage->getID();
        $authorName = $chatMessage->getAuthorName();
        $message = $chatMessage->getMessage(); 
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if($result == false) return false;
        $chatMessage->setID($this->db->lastInsertId());
        $chatMessage->setAuthorName($this->db->lastInsertId());
        $chatMessage->setMessage($this->db->lastInsertId());
        $this->chatMessages[]=$chatMessage;
    }
```

Comment: "What is the error?" is a good question. Are you outputting db/sql errors anywhere? And why do you think the problem is directly related to bindParam as your topic suggests? Do you have any output spew of what is trying to be bound? The resulting SQL? Anything?

Comment: Well that's a good point. I don't actually know where the error is. I think there is one because the result is false and there is no entry in my database after running this code...

Comment: By default, PDO errors silently. It is very highly recommended to configure your PDO object to throw useful exceptions. At the time it's connected, `$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`  Couple that with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` always when developing and testing code. Whatever goes wrong in PDO will be immediately visible.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski This is the exeption: General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database in

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski well... bindParam is setting those variables up as references, so one *can* set them after the method call. Like in the case where someone wants to loop over multiple inserts of a prepared statement. But I agree... generally its more readable to put the variable set BEFORE bindParam.

Comment: How can I change SQLite from read only to ready and write? I use XAMPP and I have a .sqlite file

Comment: ok i solved the problem it was property issue it was set on wirte only